# Is Babel 7 compliant with the ES modules specification?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, es6-modules

It sounds like there is some history with Babel not implementing ES6 module support in full compliance with the spec; I am wondering what the current state is, and having trouble finding information.

In Dr. Rauschmayer's "Exploring ES6" book, it describes the properties of an import object.

http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#sec_imports-as-views-on-exports

Specifically, "imports are live read-only views on exported values", and the following are not allowed:

```js
import { foo } from './foo';
import foo2 from './foo';
import * as foo3 from './foo';
foo = '...'; // error, foo is readonly
foo2 = '...'; // error, foo is readonly
foo3.foo = '...'; // error, foo3 is a frozen object
```

However, I have noticed a discrepancy in Babel regarding default exports that still exists in version 7:

```js
// foo.js
export function foo() {}
export default foo;

// other.js
import * as fooStuff from './foo';

fooStuff.default = function newFoo() {}; // no error
fooStuff.foo = function newFoo() {}; // error
```

This is explained by the difference in Babel output for the two cases:

```js
// default export
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
exports.default = foo;

// named export
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
Object.defineProperty(exports, "foo", {
  enumerable: true,
  get: function get() {
    return _foo.default;
  }
});
```

My understanding is that the default export is just another named export that happens to have the name "default", but it doesn't seem to be implemented that way in Babel 7.  I created a repo with various test cases at https://github.com/yossarian21/import-spec

So, my questions:

1. Is Babel actually deviating from the spec, or do I misunderstand the spec?
2. Where can I find information about Babel's plan to implement to spec?
3. Is node.js implementing import/export support in compliance with the spec?

Comment: I don't understand, are you asking why `babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs` converts to commonjs modules?

Comment: No, I am wondering why does Babel produce output that causes this to error:

`import * as foo from './foo';  foo.bar = '...';`

But this does not error?

`import * as foo from './foo';  foo.default = '...';`

Comment: I think babel is more interested in implementing all functionality as efficiently as possible, not in reproducing all errors that are called for in the spec. Afaik they don't implement the TDZ either.

Comment: "*`fooStuff.default = function newFoo() {};` - no error*" - yes, this definitely should be an error just like the assignment to `.foo`. Probably the object also is extensible (which it shouldn't be according to the spec).